# Working with NSString manipulating special characters

Tags: macos, unicode, byte, nsstring

I want to print an `NSString` byte by byte:

```objectivec
NSString *path = @"/User/user/ǢǨǣ/";
const char *byte_array = [path UTF8String];

for (unsigned char *it = byte_array; *it != 0; ++it) {
   NSLog(@"char: %c \t hex: %02x \n", *it, *it);
}
```

Producing:

```
 Ç - FFFFFFC7
 ¢ - FFFFFFA2
 Ç - FFFFFFC7
 ¨ - FFFFFFA8
 Ç - FFFFFFC7
 £ - FFFFFFA3
```

This should be the output for Ǣ(C7 A2) Ǩ(C7 A8) ǣ(C7 A3).
I think those "FFFFFF" form every "byte" affects my code. I'm wondering if is any way of manipulating paths with special characters in them.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ǢǨǣ'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `Ç¢Ç¨Ç£`. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The output is behaving as if it was signed `char *` being converted to a signed integer and then displayed as a 32-bit hex string. While I am unable to produce the exact behavior you describe (without manually casting it to a signed integer), looking at the headers, `UTF8String` is defined as:

```objectivec
@property (nullable, readonly) const char *UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER; // Convenience to return null-terminated UTF8 representation
```

And you even defined your pointer to be signed `char *`:

```objectivec
const char *byte_array = [path UTF8String];
```

Note, neither of those are `unsigned char *`, but just `char *`. (FWIW, that seems exceedingly curious to me at I always think of a “byte” as an `unsigned char`, i.e., a `uint8_t`.)

I personally would use `NSData` and `uint8_t` to avoid ambiguity:

```objectivec
NSString *path = [@"/User/user/ǢǨǣ" precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];

NSData *data = [path dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[data enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void * _Nonnull bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < byteRange.length; i++) {
        uint8_t byte = ((uint8_t *)bytes)[i];
        NSLog(@"%02x", byte);
    }
}];
```

And those last three characters came out as:

```
c7
a2
c7
a8
c7
a3
```

---

As an aside, when I did a cut-and-paste your code snippet, rather than receiving `c7a2` for `Ǣ`, I received `c386` (`Æ`) followed by `cc84` (the “combining macron”, i.e., the “combining” rendition of `¯`). I do not know whether Stack Overflow or your editor introduced that, but this is a common problem when looking at hexadecimal representations of UTF8 characters, as there are multiple possible representations of the same character. If you are really looking at hex UTF8 representations, you may want to standardize this with, for example, [`precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma?language=objc), as shown above.